# Which statistical test should I use? Pre-post intervention comparisions and post-post comparisons

Tags: spss, t-test

In my experiment I compare the jump height of participants pre and post 2 separate interventions.

All participants completed baseline measures of jump height. Participants then underwent a training intervention followed by post test measurements. On a separate occasion the same participants completed a different intervention before post test measurements were taken.

I believe I should use paired t-tests to compare these groups as the same participants were tested pre and post. However, I also want to compare the post test scores from intervention 1 with the post test scores from intervention 2 (to see if there were significant differences between the two interventions).

Is there a test I should use to achieve this in one? Or do I use the paired t-tests for pre and post comparisons and a further test for the post-post comparison?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not clear on the experiment. All participants were exposed to the two interventions? So for the 'post-post' analysis you are comparing the difference between having just one intervention as opposed to the same people having both interventions.

Comment: I think a repeated measures ANOVA would be appropriate in your case. I'm make the assumption that @Simon asks about above, that all participants experienced both interventions.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I'm new to the network.
I do not know which statistical program you use, I use SPSS.
If I understood correctly (I'm not native to the language) you have three measures of the same individuals.
If your data have a normal distribution, if there is homogeneity of variances and if the variances of the three measurements are not different (p> 0.05) you can use Anova for repeated measures.

Comment: This is a definite improvement, but you still should try to explain/justify your answer in more detail,  If you can, please edit